# Flutter ObjectBox: getAll() stream not responding

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I have the following objectBox class:

```html
class ObjectBox {
  late final Store _store;
  late final Box<EventData> _eventBox; // EventData is some model I made

  ObjectBox._init(this._store) {
    _eventBox = Box<EventData>(_store);
  }

  static Future<ObjectBox> init() async {
    final store = await openStore();

    return ObjectBox._init(store);
  }


  Stream<List<EventData>> getEvents() => _eventBox
      .query()
      .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
      .map((query) => query.find());
}
```

Inside my Bloc class, I'm trying to load all of the events when I initialize it like this:

```html
class ClockBloc extends Bloc<ClockEvent, ClockState> {
  final Stream<List<EventData>> streamEvents;
  ClockBloc({required this.streamEvents}) : super(const ClockState()) {
      on<ClockEvent>(
        _fetchEvents, 
        //transformer: droppable(),
      ); // this is where I initialize the events
  }
  
  Future<void> _fetchEvents(
      ClockEvent event,
      Emitter<ClockState> emit,
    ) async {
      await emit.onEach(
      streamEvents,
      onData: (data) {
        print('${data.runtimeType} ${data.length}'); // It prints all of the items, but never comes out of the loop
      },
    );
      print('You won't see this line'); // my app never reaches this line as it's waiting for the stream indefinitely for some reason..
    }
  }
}
```

**However,** when I simply pass the stream into a StreamBuilder, I see the items just fine. So my question is this: Is it even possible to convert a stream into a list? And if so, how?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: check https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-async/Stream/toList.html - they say: "When this stream ends, the returned future is completed with that list." - basically your stream never ends

Comment: Yeah, I figuered. But the stream is basically empty on initialization (it's a brand new database), so I don't know why it never ends..

Comment: When I first load the app, I want to load the existing items (that happens inside my Bloc initialization function). Nothing can be added into the stream unless you press some button

Comment: https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency

Comment: I followed the guide and added transformer: droppable(), to my only bucket, and I'm experiencing the same effect.

Comment: you don't need any `droppable()` - all you have to do is to use `forEach` - check the link I posted again and search for `forEach`

Comment: basically read whole `"Blocs and streams"` section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254337/discussion-between-preem-palver2-and-pskink).